# Tools for building charting server that creates / caches server-side rendered image charts?

Tags: node.js, apache, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a set of apps being built on different platforms, which need charts. Rather than pull the data into the app and render the charts natively, I wanted to instead pull in the charts as images, which are processed server side.

I searched online to see if others have done this, but I can't find anything. Is anyone aware of any libraries or tools that will:

1. Generate an chart
2. Has some sort of static file serving of the charts
3. Does some sort of caching / expiration of charts so they are not rendered each time a call is made?

Ideally this is something that would scale on S3 or so.

I've found something like [Highcharts-server-render](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts), but it only does #1 from the list above, and would still require work to do #2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem here. Do you know all permutations of the types of charts that would be requested? Is the data static that the charts are based on? Do you control the updating of the charts? If you can answer yes to those 3 then you can try it.

- The HighCharts export server is definitely the way to go.
- Send in all your chart permutations as individual json calls to the renderer.
- After each rendering of the chart, copy the image with some uniquely identifying name to a web-accessible folder.
- Serve up the images as static links from that web-accessible folder.

Parts 2-3 you could write in various flavors of code. Seems a bit over the top to me, but possible.

Or...

Have highcharts render the chart like it normally would and you still have the export server to serve them up. I honestly cant see why you would want to use a dynamic charting library to not create dynamic and interactive charts.

Comment: Thanks. Ya, parts 1-4 are what I was imagining was required, but given that this *seems* like it may be something others would do, I was hoping that there was something built already. I wanted to avoid having to build my own rendering/caching/serving layer. What did you mean by your last statement? The goal is to have static images that can be rendered on non-browser clients. The charts are fixed data that 'expires' after ~1 day.

Comment: @Steve, What I mean is that HighCharts is a dynamic/interactive charting library. The user can pan/zoom, hide series, etc. Using HighCharts but not using the inter-activeness seems to me to be a loss.

Comment: I guess I was considering high charts only because it provides a server to create the static images. For the current case, pan/zoom/etc are not important and can be dropped.

Comment: @Steve, sounds reasonable. You don't mention a language preference but this sounds like it can be a simple batch script to take the params needed each month and loop through them to send to the export server via commandline and then move/rename the files to web-server location.

Comment: Ya, I was hoping to not have to write the full system end-to-end, and also wanted it to be done on-demand, since the charts would have to be updated daily, and would rather only do it the first time that chart is requested for that given date.